# jquery submit after jquery $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

$.get(link, function(data, status) {
document.getElementById("test").value = data;
}                                                                                   });
$('#formtest').submit();

with Firefox work fine but with google chrome submit is done before "test" element change value.
I want submit is done after $.get is done. How can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: Well put the `$('#formtest').submit();` into the `$.get` callback function, same as you already did with the value assignment ...?

Answer (score 0):

$.get needs some time to get response .So , place the .submit() code inside of function of $.get

It looks like this.

```
$.get(link, 
 function(data,status) {
 $("#test").value = data;
$('#formtest').submit();
 }

);
```